# How to remove a string element from an array everywhere in a SQLite table?

Tags: arrays, sqlite, json-remove

Considering a SQLite table where one column (named `domain`) is an `array` of `strings` with no particular index/order.
Example: `["google", "apple", "twitter"]`

How can I update the all table to delete all `google` items?
In my example, result should be `["apple", "twitter"]`.

I've started with:

```
UPDATE events
SET domain = json_remove(domain, "google")
```

But (1) it doesn't work and (2) it seems that I must use `index` with `json_remove`.

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CSIh7dct).

---

EDIT

I tried with:

```
UPDATE events
SET domain = REPLACE(domain, '"google", ', '')
WHERE domain LIKE '%"google"%';
```

...but quote escaping is hard and it doesn't work if `google` is at the end of the array (= there is no `,`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manipulation of the json array as a string is tricky, but it is feasible:

```
UPDATE events
SET domain = '[' || TRIM(REPLACE(',' || TRIM(json(domain), '[]') || ',', ',' || '"google"' || ',', ','), ',') || ']'
WHERE domain LIKE '%"google"%';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IQNX616g).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try, but is there a cleaner way? (e.g. the way I store my array?)

Comment: @charnould a *cleaner* way would be to *unnest* each json array's items to separate rows, remove any unwanted rows and recompose the arrays to rows with aggregation. I don't think that this would be simple and I'm sure that it would be far less efficient.